# Sequelize 6.5 didn't return complete child relationships & limit the key name

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

here's my question.
I'm trying to get the nested relationships by Sequelize.

```
let results = await FarmVisitQuestionnaire.findOne({
        where: { Customer_ID, id:2 },
        include: [{
          model: FarmVisitSection,
          include: [{
            model: FarmVisitQuestion,
            include: [{
              model: FarmVisitQuestionOption,
            }]
          }]
        }],
      });
```

Everything works well excepts for the deepest relationship `FarmVisitQuestionOption`. It didn't return the complete data in `FarmVisitQuestionOption` section, there're two `FarmVisitQuestionOption` data but only one `FarmVisitQuestionOption` is returned ("i":1).  And the key names in `FarmVisitQuestionOption` are limited to only the first character as below:

```
"questionnaires": {
        "id": 2,
        "Customer_ID": "3380",
        "Title": "Form title",
        "createdAt": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.292Z",
        "updatedAt": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.292Z",
        "FarmVisitSections": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "Title": "Section title",
                "Description": "Section description",
                "Order": 0,
                "createdAt": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.295Z",
                "updatedAt": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.295Z",
                "FarmVisitQuestionnaireId": 2,
                "FarmVisitQuestions": [
                    {
                        "id": 1,
                        "Title": "Question title?",
                        "Description": "Question description / extra info",
                        "Order": 0,
                        "Required": "true",
                        "Type": "checkbox1",
                        "createdAt": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.299Z",
                        "updatedAt": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.299Z",
                        "FarmVisitSectionId": 2,
                        "FarmVisitQuestionOptions": [
                            {
                                "i": 1,
                                "L": "First Option",
                                "V": "1",
                                "c": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.303Z",
                                "u": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.303Z",
                                "F": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

My DB was set up correctly:
[FarmVisitQuestionOption table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ7vc.png)

However, the correct `FarmVisitQuestionOption` section should be:

```
"FarmVisitQuestionOptions": 
                      [
                            {
                                "id": 1,
                                "Label": "First Option",
                                "Value": "1",
                                "createdAt": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.303Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.303Z",
                                "FarmVisitQuestionId": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 2,
                                "Label": "Second Option",
                                "Value": "2",
                                "createdAt": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.303Z",
                                "updatedAt": "2022-07-05T19:42:50.303Z",
                                "FarmVisitQuestionId": 1
                            }
                        ]
```

Can anyone help me with this issue? Any insights would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use PostgreSQL you need to turn on the option `minifyAliases` in Sequelize instance due to Postgres alias character limit of 64.
See [the official Sequelize documentation](https://sequelize.org/v5/class/lib/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#instance-constructor-constructor)

Comment: That works after I turned on the minifyAliases option. Thanks!